# How can I get a list of column names using the google spreadsheet api?

Tags: java, google-api

I am using a list based feed to access my spreadsheet in google docs. How can I get a list of the column names/ columnHeaders?

I figured out the answer to this myself, but since I couldn't find the answer on StackOverflow, or in the java doc for the google api, I thought would contribute my solution.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you know how to access the worksheet to begin with, so you are responsible for writing the following two functions.

```
SpreadsheetService service = getspreadsheetService();
WorksheetEntry worksheet = getGoogleWorksheet();
```

Here is how you get your list of columnHeaders:

```
URL url = worksheet.getListFeedUrl();
ListFeed rows = service.getFeed(url, ListFeed.class);
ListEntry row = rows.getEntries().get(0);
Set<String> columnHeadings = row.getCustomElements().getTags();
```

Comment: Is this possible in PHP?

Comment: This will not work if the worksheet has a header row, but no data rows.

Comment: @VivinPaliath I face this problem, I want to check column names to see if they conform, _before_ I start inserting data rows... Have you already discovered how to do that?

Comment: @heltonbiker The solution by MS_SL comes close. I ended up not needing it, but my solution was pretty similar. You can get check out the tags on the custom elements to see if they conform.

Comment: @VivinPaliath thanks for your answer! I actually managed to solve my problem with the other answer as you said :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the CellFeed and iterate through all cells with a row value of 1.

However, you'll need to strip out all characters that aren't alphanumeric, decimals or dashes, and also strip out any leading digits too, which can be done with a regex and the `String.replaceAll()` method.

```
URL cellFeedUrl = worksheet.getCellFeedUrl();
CellFeed cellFeed = service.getFeed(cellFeedUrl, CellFeed.class);
String[] columnNames = new String[worksheet.getColCount()];
for (CellEntry entry : cellFeed.getEntries())
    if (entry.cell.getRow() == 1)
    {
        String val = entry.cell.getValue().toLowerCase();
        String parsed = val.replaceAll('^[0-9]*|[^a-z0-9\-\.]', '');
        columnNames[entry.cell.getCol()] = parsed;
    }
```